# Program cannot open file, but the file is already there

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, file, fopen

I am writing a program that will open an image file, but strange thing happened. This is the output from cmd:

```
C:\Users\Karl\Pictures>testcvconsole mypic.jpg
argv[0]==testcvconsole
argv[1]==mypic.jpg
fopen is null
strerror(errno)==No such file or directory
```

Are there something I should consider when fopen simply failed to open my file when the file is right there along side with the executable file in the same directory?

This is on Windows 7, Visual Studios Express 2010. C++.

**EDIT**: code below

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

int goMain(int argc, char** argv);

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
 goMain(argc, (char**)argv);
 return 0;
}

int goMain( int argc, char** argv ){

 if (argv[1] != NULL){
  printf("argv[0]==%S\nargv[1]==%S\n", argv[0], argv[1]);

  if (fopen(argv[1], "r") == NULL){
   printf("fopen is null\n");
   printf(strerror(errno));
  }

 }

 return 0;
}
```

**EDIT2**:

I have tried

```
char *workingDir =_getcwd(NULL, 0);
printf("workingDir == %S", workingDir);
```

as TomK has suggested and it returned:

```
workingDir ==
```

Nothing at all. Hmm...

**EDIT3**:
I am getting something. I tried

```
argv[1] = "C:/Users/Karl/Pictures/mypic.jpg";
```

And fopen can open it. This statement above is inserted right before the fopen.

Comment: 1. How do we know the picture is actually there? 2. Gimmeh some code!

Comment: Please show us your source code.

Comment: updated as requested. @Billy ONeal: because I put both picture and .exe in the same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make absolutely *sure* they are in the same directory. I'm saying this because you're using Visual Studio, for which the "same" directory isn't always so clear, because it depends on how you execute the executable through the IDE.

```
C:\Users\Karl\Pictures>testcvconsole mypic.jpg
```

Are you sure `mypic.jpg` is located in `C:\Users\Karl\Pictures` ?

Comment: I build the .exe, copy it and place it in Pictures folder, so shouldn't it be in the same directory?

Comment: Yes. Is `mypic.jpg` also there? Could you open it by other means (say, some script or batch file) ?

Comment: Simple test, @unknownthreat. While you're at a command prompt in the `C:\Users\Karl\Pictures` directory, just type in `mypic.jpg` and hit ENTER. If the file _is_ there, it should open in IE or Firefox or whatever application you have bound to JPG files.

Comment: @unknownthreat: as another test, could you write a simple main without the unicode stuff (`main`, not `_tmain`), and without the `stdafx` as well (just create an empty console project and add a new .c file into it with the code in `main`)

Comment: Aha, using main instead of _tmain work. So unicode is the cause of the problem, is it not? Fair enough, but then, sometimes I need to open files that are not named in English; I need unicode. So in this case, what are some of the things I should look for?

Comment: @unknownthreat: there seems to be a problem with the unicode version in the current directory which isn't recognized

Comment: I have marked your post as correct, as your suggestion for using main instead of _tmain worked.

Answer (score 1):

1. Can u check whether the working directory is correct?

   ```
   #include <direct.h>

   char *workingDir =_getcwd(NULL, 0);
   ```
2. Can you run your application with admin privileges?

Answer (score 0):

Usually the .exe is created in sub-directory either Debug or Release - try giving the absolute path to the image ...

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem, and it turned out that Visual Studio's runtime wasn't setting the current directory.  I never figured out the problem:  instead I simply used an absolute path.  Without the absolute path, your program is looking in `C:\`.  You can also try using `".\\mypic.jpg"` or [`GetCurrentDirectory()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364934%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).