# 'fopen' returns NULL - "no such file or directory"

Tags: c, xcode, terminal, fopen

I've written a super simple C command line tool that's supposed to read a file out from the path specified in `argv[1]`. I'm debugging using [Xcode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xcode) on OS X, so the working directory at the time of running is an Xcode-created directory separate from the file I want to read. (Xcode plugs in the arguments automatically, so that's not the problem.) I suspect the problem is related to my not understanding how `fopen` works. When I put in a path name, is it relative to the working directory? Will it work if I use the absolute path?

I've checked [this post](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCwQFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987626/fopen-returns-null-pointer&ei=H8M8UtO-GoiQ9QTkzoDoCA&usg=AFQjCNF3UQr8OI7fE7PvvRIiZVFn41KGTw&sig2=dN9ZtViIU1KoRxjmcn22ag&bvm=bv.52434380,d.eWU), [this one](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQFjAB&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6686318/fopen-returning-null-pointer-but-file-definitely-exists&ei=H8M8UtO-GoiQ9QTkzoDoCA&usg=AFQjCNGchDKnwlHEETHi6s2uIr7lz1GArw&sig2=fpSThCAAKixpTSOLbAAibA&bvm=bv.52434380,d.eWU), and [this one](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCoQFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720936/program-cannot-open-file-but-the-file-is-already-there&ei=ZMM8Upr2G4Tu8QSZzoCQCg&usg=AFQjCNFSJ-Kf1AHQ1-DsVkUrL1yG3SeDCg&sig2=86eeExn3w9WFsu3K3yXhsg&bvm=bv.52434380,d.eWU), but they don't seem to help me in this case.

Here's the code I'm using - it's in the `main` function:

```
for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++)
    printf("arg%i: %s\n", i, argv[i]);

if (argc > 1)
{
    //Open the file specified by the first argument
    system("pwd");
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");    //Always returns NULL

    if (file)
        //This isn't ever reached
    else
        printf("%s\n", strerror(errno));        
}
```

The output looks like this:

```
arg0: /Users/home/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VSSequenceAlignment-avlfehlrtqiybygqfgueezoysnyi/Build/Products/Debug/VSSequenceAlignment
arg1: C:/Users/venkateshsivaramanDP/Documents/test/testdoc.txt
/Users/venkateshsivaramanDP/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/VSSequenceAlignment-avlfehlrtqiybygqfgueezoysnyi/Build/Products/Debug
No such file or directory
```

After changing the arg1 to use forward slashes it hasn't changed the error. Admittedly it's a step closer to the actual problem.

Comment: `argv[0]` seems to be an OSX-style path, whereas `argv[1]` seems to be a Windows-style path; what's up with that?

Comment: I saw that some people were using the backslashes on one of the SO posts I linked, I think. It didn't seem to me like there was a difference until you said so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your path is wrong; you are using a Windows path.

Compare your supplied path to arg0, specifying the path to the executable. `arg1` has to be in the same style.

Comment: If you mean the backslashes, changing them around didn't help either way. I still get the same error.

Comment: unix paths don't start with `C:`. go to the file you want to open in terminal and execute `echo $(pwd)/file_you_want_to_open`. This is the path you need to provide.

Comment: There we go! Thank you, it turned out to be the C: causing the problem. If you want to add that to your answer, I'll go ahead and accept it. Because I may need to use an external disk to store the file I want to read in the future, how would I go about supplying that path?

Comment: That's entirely depending on the OS. in OSX, such volumes are in `/Volumes/`, while in others, like ubuntu or debian, it usually is in `/mnt/`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolute paths work with `fopen`, but that's not your problem. I think that your problem comes from the content of `arg[1]`, and I think it contains `C:\Users\home\Documents\test\testdoc.txt` which is a Windows path and you're on OS X.